# What is the minimum Android version supported by Meteor? (for cordova mobile app)

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

That's the question really - quite simple!

This is for the latest version of Meteor to date 1.1.0.2.

I understand that it uses Cordova 4.2 which has it's own version constraints. But I also ready somewhere about supporting only Android versions with more than 5% live population.

Can someone shed light on the truth please?

(I am particularly interested if 4.1.2 is supported.)

Answer (score 1):

For Meteor 1.2.0.2. I tried to deploy to Android 2.3.3(API10) and couldn't make my app work with that version because of this unresolved bug:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2822

I would say that the minimum required version for vainilla Meteor is now **Android 4.0(API14)**, there are many issues when trying to deploy for older versions.

As your question, **you should be fine deploying to 4.1.2 version**, unless you are using an incompatible third party library.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Do you know what is *supported* though? For whatever definition of support you'd want to take for Open Source software :)

Comment: Well i couldn't find an *official* statement about a *supported* version, in words of a member of Meteor Team earlier this year:
*Meteor is low on engineering resources. There are dozens of projects in Meteor and Mobile is only a part of it. It is important strategically, it is a very useful feature for a lot of our users, but we got to make decisions on what projects get the most attention. Right now, nobody at MDG is working on the Cordova support full-time. I do work on some maintenance and updates from time to time, but the main focus is on other projects.*

Comment: With that in mind, I wouldn't expect additional efforts to make Meteor compatible with older versions or offer an *official support*. In practice, the minimum *supported* version is whatever version is supported by the Cordova package included in Meteor, in this case Android4(API14).